# Strategy for measuring performance of an iOS app

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, instruments

I have a simple case of an iOS application I would like to measure: a UITableView built with custom extended cells. Each cell is a composition of a main views and some subviews. Based on some criteria I am hiding or showing subviews in table cell.

Supposing I have to decide if adding subviews when needed, or built xib with all the outlets and hide/show when needed.

What could be the best approach for deciding between those two ?

Supposing also you didn't read Apple guidelines about composition of cell, what concrete steps you would do either via code (by putting NSLog statement for example), or via Xcode instruments (which one to choose etc...) to confirm the choice.

This is quite a new matter for me, so please be as much specific as you can.

Answer (score -1):

This http://blog.giorgiocalderolla.com/2011/04/16/customizing-uitableviewcells-a-better-way/ is a great resource.

Having many subviews with transparent backgrounds degrades scrolling performance.

Dynamically adding subViews could get difficult to track, and if you don't do it "right" then you'll end up with cells with too many "extra" subviews, via the cell reuse queueing mechanism.

You'll have to add the subViews in the init method of the cell itself and not in the cellForRow method of your data source. (unless you're using some way to track the creation/availability of any given subview, like viewWithTag etc.)

Comment: thanks for your answer, the link is a very good resource, but my question is related to which instruments you would use to prove this

Comment: Good question. Well, at least you can visually identify the stutter-step. I'm not sure how you can prove it, with identifying CPU bottlenecks and such, because performance is usually identified more by the end user when they notice the "buttery smooth" scrolling